# Iterative E2E tests in Protractor

Tags: protractor

The project on which I am working requires me to repeat a product selection process with edits, deletes the product and starts again. At my best guess this will be repeated several hundred times possibly.

The outline process looks like this:

```
1. Spec 1 creates the empty room into which products will be placed.

2. Spec 2 selects the first product category (baths), selects the first 
product in that category - which is placed into the 'empty room'. Next, 
various options are added/removed from the product..for example, taps, 
side-panels etc. Some assertions will take place, then this product 
will be removed (there's a nice simple on button remove.)
```

Spec 2 would then be repeated for the next bath in the bath category and so on through Baths, basins, showers, toilets...the lot!!.

Is it possible to create a load of variables based on a seperate data file stored in the framework, and call the variables in 'spec2'? Is there a slicker way of achieving this?

Comment: For this data file, is your intention to have each `variable` store a product configuration? And then read the data from the file into a list and use the list to configure the product/room?

Comment: Each product is listed on an external spreadsheet. The listing is in the form of a URL pointing to a location in the product database - here's an example `<img _ngcontent-c62="" src="https://kingfisher.scene7.com/is/image/Kingfisher/productTemplate?$baseImage=Kingfisher/03827215_01c&amp;$CATEGORY_LARGE$" alt="Image of Cooke &amp; Lewis Strand Corner Bath">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use [browser.params()](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/7f968e022a7f7ebcda8955651f2907c1a25ecc22/lib/config.ts#L472) for this. You could store the data in your protractor config or use an external params file and just import/require it in your config.

You can just store the product configurations in a json object, read that object into a list and then iterate over the list to setup each one.

```
params: {
  productConfigurations: [
    product: {
      category: "baths",
      options: {
        taps: true,
        side-panels: false 
      }
    },
    product: {
      //etc...
    }
  ]  
}
```

And then in your test you can just assign the value to an array and off you go...

```
const productConfigs = browser.params.productConfigurations;

for(const product in productConfigs) {
  //do your product setup and assertions in here
}
```